# OneDrive not syncing properly

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive Android does not update OneDrive on PC, but OneDrive PC does update OneDrive Android:
    - If I edit a file on my PC, both the PC and Android will open that version.
    - If I edit that file on Android and save, then Android opens the new version, but the PC opens the original version.
    - If I edit the original version on the PC, Both the PC and Android will open the 3rd version.

Am I the only one? Is there a setting problem?
It seems like OneDrive Android App does not sync to the cloud even if refresh is pushed.

Galaxy S4
Kit-Kat 4.4.4
OneDrive 2.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. Open a **Word** document on **OneDrive** using **Hancom Office**, for example,  edit and save it.

The document is saved in a **cache** on my tablet (labelled onedrive) but never updated elsewhere. The only way to update is to "**save as**" somewhere you can find it an reshare from the tablet manually.

This makes it a half useful app on tablets. Works fine'ish between PCs

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that you are editing the cloud version of the file.

Some apps download the file locally for editing, so it would need to be re-uploaded for the changes to be visible in the cloud.

So it depends on the file being edited. For simple text files, changes should be updated automatically.

Comment: "There is no auto synchronisation back to the cloud with these kind of storage apps." - untrue, DropBox auto uploads/syncs the files.  This obviates the entire concept of cloud storage.                It begs the question, how do you upload the new file, I cannot see how....

Comment: I just tried.  If I edit the cloud version it updates.  If I "Favorite" (D/L a copy 'within' DB) and edit the Favorite it is updated.  What do you mean by "Download"?  If you save a seperate copy outside of DB of course it won't sync.   In fact, when I save the file on Android, My PC pops up a notification saying Dropbox updated the file - no extra activity needed.

Comment: It begs the question, how do you upload the new file, I cannot see how....

Comment: There is an upload button at the bottom of the screen. You just pick the new file from your device storage.

Comment: Let me get this straight, to use OneDrive I need to explicitly and manually D/L the file to my phone, navigate to that location on my phone to open and edit it, then manually upload the file back to the cloud?!?!?  When I edit the "OneDrive file" using my phone it is a "hidden" and "duplicate" file somewhere on my phone but not available on OneDrive?  Best to use DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

My Android OneDrive app was not displaying my updated files.
I followed Microsoft advice and Force stopped, cleared data and cache, uninstalled and reinstalled with Google Play.
I tried this 3 times and it didn't help.
Then I installed the Amazon app and downloaded OneDrive app through the Amazon app, and it worked!!
I can now view all my latest updated files.
I thought I should share my experience so that it may help others with a similar issue.

Answer (score -4):

Try OneSync. OneDrive support recommended it.

Comment: Can you link to this app?

Comment: And also some explanation and how-to if possible.